# Can I detect how far a bluetooth device is before connecting to it?

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am trying out the Bluetooth low energy bluetooth devices

And i would like to know how far a bluetooth device is without connecting to it.
Is it possible to find this data?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that's the 'protocol way'.
Below you find some others related threads.

> You can use the proximity profile to get the RSSI information. However
>   to find the actual distance of the chip would be a much more
>   complicated effort. While all you get is the signal strength, it
>   cannot be used to accurately give distance. You can at best do a range
>   of distances and even then that would be accurate.
>
> The problem here, the range of the antenna varies with the design of
>   the board, type of plastics, environment the board will be placed in.
>   So it is very difficult to give an accurate location with a single
>   antenna.
>
> I know there is effort in Bluetooth SIG to get locationing. But that
>   is a complex system with multiple antennas and algorithms to find
>   exact loaction of a device.
>
> [Link](http://e2e.ti.com/support/wireless_connectivity/f/538/p/286526/999309.aspx#999309)

- [Android Documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth-le.html)
- [Other Chat about the subject](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/appinventor/RtwFL79I4pQ)

[]'s

Comment: Is it possible, by RSSI alone to determine how far the device is?
I have 2 devices in the same room. I want to be sure that only when i am within 1 meter of a device, that i will respond to it. Otherwise i want to ignore it. Can RSSI give me this information ?

Comment: Rssi can't give you this information. Two reasons why not: 1. Same rssi number can be in 1 meter and in 4 meters. 2. The rssi behaves different for different device manufactures.